# Creating a web service project

Tags: android

How do I start a project wherein I can design an application which fetches weather forecasts from existing web sites?

Comment: This is an extremely broad question.  I recommend reading the Developer Guide. http://developer.android.com/guide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use google weather api for starting the project. Here's an example: 
[Android Weather Forecast Google](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/android-weather-forecast-google-weather-api-description-t337.html)

Comment: This question is tagged with android only